Flutter App crashing in only Android device
I Really need help in this I'm trying this from many days and still not figure out the problem
When i run this app in ios simulator then it runs fine but when i run in any android device then it crashes immediately I not getting the problem
My Debug console after app launch to crash
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2637): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2637): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2637): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 2637): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 2637): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2637): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2637): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator( 2637): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:63706/2UBZY5eep1A=/ws
Connected to the VM Service.
I/flutter ( 2637): eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NmU3ZmEwMjliZGZlMTAwNmUzOTY0MzkiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjcxNzMyNTMsImV4cCI6MTc0Mjk0MTI1MywidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.b0PWqexRxdiypAdbi8mdn14JQaYdLPerEryw3k1sVTU
I/flutter ( 2637): eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NmU3ZmEwMjliZGZlMTAwNmUzOTY0MzkiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjcxNzMyNTMsImV4cCI6MTc1ODcwOTI1MywidHlwZSI6InJlZnJlc2gifQ.xu95VDDLfimL0nAiMvM0ZD2R6REsxYAOj5ASR1WMnBw
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=12.65ms min=3.00ms max=120.38ms count=50
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=4.20ms min=1.37ms max=8.33ms count=61
D/ProfileInstaller( 2637): Installing profile for com.example.vezigo
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=6.14ms min=1.10ms max=199.55ms count=57
Reloaded 1 of 1157 libraries in 243ms.

After restart
E/flutter ( 2637): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: TimeoutException after 0:00:30.000000: Future not completed
E/flutter ( 2637): 
Restarted application in 617ms.
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher( 2637): sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=false callback=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity$1@bf7ddac
I/flutter ( 2637): eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NmU3ZmEwMjliZGZlMTAwNmUzOTY0MzkiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjcxNzMyNTMsImV4cCI6MTc0Mjk0MTI1MywidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyJ9.b0PWqexRxdiypAdbi8mdn14JQaYdLPerEryw3k1sVTU
I/flutter ( 2637): eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2NmU3ZmEwMjliZGZlMTAwNmUzOTY0MzkiLCJpYXQiOjE3MjcxNzMyNTMsImV4cCI6MTc1ODcwOTI1MywidHlwZSI6InJlZnJlc2gifQ.xu95VDDLfimL0nAiMvM0ZD2R6REsxYAOj5ASR1WMnBw
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=61040.50ms min=1.08ms max=244092.02ms count=4
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=3.28ms min=0.89ms max=9.21ms count=61
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=2.55ms min=0.96ms max=6.38ms count=60
D/EGL_emulation( 2637): app_time_stats: avg=5.00ms min=1.14ms max=163.79ms count=59

flutter doctor
arleven@Arlevens-Mini vezigo-flutter % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1-0.0.pre.3, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
    ! Upstream repository https://github.com/tanuu007/flutter.git is not a standard remote.
      Set environment variable "FLUTTER_GIT_URL" to https://github.com/tanuu007/flutter.git to dismiss this error.
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/to/macos-android-setup for more details.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for Arleven’s iPad. Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area
      network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Also my homescreen where the app crashes if there any problem
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vezigo/Api_Models/banner.dart';
import 'package:vezigo/Screens/categories.dart';
import 'package:vezigo/Models/colors.dart';
import 'package:vezigo/Screens/cart_screen.dart';
import 'package:vezigo/Providers/item_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vezigo/Models/category.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:badges/badges.dart' as badges;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:vezigo/Screens/search.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import '../Api_Models/list_products.dart';
import '../Providers/fav_provider.dart';
import 'item_details.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MyHomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomeScreen> createState() => _MyHomeScreenState();
}
class _MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  int _currentPage = 0;
  final TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  String _appBarTitle = 'Vezigo';
  bool _isSearchVisible = false;
 final PageController _pageController = PageController();
  Timer? _timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureProducts = fetchProducts();
    _futureBanners = fetchbanner();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
  _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer timer) {
  if (_pageController.hasClients) {
    if (_currentPage < 2) {
      _currentPage++;
    } else {
      _currentPage = 0;
    }
    _pageController.animateToPage(
      _currentPage,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );
  }
});

  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _timer?.cancel();
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  void _scrollListener() {
    double offset = _scrollController.offset;
    if (offset > 400) {
      setState(() {
        _appBarTitle = 'Fruits';
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _appBarTitle = 'Vezigo';
      });
    }
  }
  Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('${AppColors.api}/products'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = json.decode(response.body);
    final Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = responseMap['data'];
    final List<dynamic> productList = dataMap['results'];
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> productIds = productList.map((json) => Product.fromJson(json).id).toList();
    await prefs.setStringList('productIds', productIds);
    return productList.map((json) => Product.fromJson(json)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load products');
  }
}

//Banner Api
Future<List<BannerItem>> fetchbanner() async{
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('${AppColors.api}/app/banners'));
  if(response.statusCode == 200){
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseMap = json.decode(response.body);
    final Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = responseMap['data'];
    final List<dynamic> bannerData = dataMap['results'];
    return bannerData.map((json) => BannerItem.fromJson(json)).toList();

  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load banners');
  }
}
late Future<List<Product>> _futureProducts;
late Future<List<BannerItem>> _futureBanners;
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final favoriteProvider = Provider.of<FavoriteProvider>(context);
    final cartProvider = Provider.of<Cart>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          _appBarTitle,
          style: const TextStyle(color: AppColors.textColor),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: AppColors.appbarColor,
        scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
        leading: const SizedBox(width: 70),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _isSearchVisible = !_isSearchVisible;
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search, size: 30, color: AppColors.textColor),
          ),
          badges.Badge(
            position: badges.BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 0, end: 3),
            badgeStyle:const badges.BadgeStyle(
              badgeColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            badgeAnimation: const badges.BadgeAnimation.fade(
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            ),
            showBadge: cartProvider.items.isNotEmpty,
            badgeContent: Text(
              cartProvider.items.length.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              tooltip: 'cart',
              icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, size: 30, color: AppColors.textColor),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const CartScreen()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.appbarColor,
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Visibility(
                  visible: _isSearchVisible,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      onTap: ()async {
                            List<Product> productList = await _futureProducts; 
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => SearchScreen(productList: productList)));
                      },
                      controller: _searchController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        labelText: 'Search Your Groceries',
                        suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: AppColors.appbarColor),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                FutureBuilder<List<BannerItem>>(
                  future: _futureBanners,
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                       return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                      }else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                        return const Center(child: Text('No products available'));
                       } else {
                        final banners = snapshot.data!;  
                  return AnimatedSize(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                          Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 249, 255, 249),
  ),
  child: PageView.builder(
    controller: _pageController,
    onPageChanged: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPage = index;
      });
    },
    itemCount: banners.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        
        onTap: () async {
              final url = Uri.parse(banners[index].url);
           if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
            await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
          } else {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(content: Text('Could not launch $url')),
            );
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            color: AppColors.lightTheme,
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, 
          child: Image.network(
            banners[index].image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity, 
            
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
const SizedBox(height: 10),
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: List.generate(banners.length, (index) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
      width: 10,
      height: 10,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: _currentPage == index
            ? AppColors.buttonColor
            : Colors.green.shade200,
      ),
    );
  }),
),

                         const   SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Categories',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                           Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          CategoryItem(
                            title: 'Fruits',
                            imagePath: 'assets/images/orange.png',
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>const CategoriesScreen(
                    categoryTitle: 'fruit',
                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          CategoryItem(
                            title: 'Veggies',
                            imagePath: 'assets/images/veggies.png',
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>const CategoriesScreen(
                    categoryTitle: 'vegetable',
                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                            const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Popular',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                           
                            FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
                          future: _futureProducts,
                          
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                            } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                              return const Center(child: Text('No products available'));
                            } else {
                              final products = snapshot.data!;
                              return Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    childAspectRatio: 0.99,
                  ),
                  itemCount: products.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final product = products[index];
                    final isFavorite = favoriteProvider.isFavorite(product);
                  
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ItemDetailsScreen(productId: product.id),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 5,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Flexible(
                                    flex: 2,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(15)),
                                      child: Container(
                                        color: AppColors.lightTheme,
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          product.imageUrl,
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          product.title,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        RichText(
                                          text: TextSpan(
                                            children: <TextSpan>[
                                              TextSpan(
                                                text: '₹${product.marketPrice}',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  color: AppColors.priceColor,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                             
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                top: 8,
                                right: 8,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: AppColors.lightTheme,
                                    shape: const CircleBorder(),
                                  ),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                                    color: AppColors.buttonColor,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    favoriteProvider.toggleFavorite(product);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                  
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
  }}),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Also when i run flutter run command then app runs properly and also works everything well
Please anyone can help i am stcuk from many days

I Researched about this and i got the solution my flutter app was having problem in kotlin version which was min and i changed that into latest version which is now 1.9.20 , Thank you

Try with enabling Developer mode on your Android device, Flutter doctor says that.

You mean Developer options? Still crashing
on=SHOW_SOFT_INPUT
D/InsetsController( 9042): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
I/ImeTracker( 9042): com.example.vezigo:3dfa9d75: onCancelled at PHASE_CLIENT_APPLY_ANIMATION
I/ImeTracker( 9042): com.example.vezigo:8214e404: onRequestShow at ORIGIN_CLIENT reason SHOW_SOFT_INPUT fromUser false
D/InputMethodManager( 9042): showSoftInput() view=io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{c13d058 VFE...... .F...... 0,0-1080,2337 #1 aid=1073741824} flags=0 reason=SHOW_SOFT_INPU

You have to go to settings on your phone and enable Developer mode. Search on Google how to do that specifically for your phone.

I did but its not working

Are you trying to start the app with phone connected to pc with usb cable or you are installing and running the apk file?

yes i tried this also and also in emulator in both physical and virtual device the app is crashing

Then I can suggest you to try to look good in prerequisites for every package you use in the app, like for example Geolocator that you use. Maybe there are settings that you must include for them to work properly on Android. If you were doing something like this for IOS, there should be for Androida also, to add some lines of configuration or something like that.

The same thing happened to me a few months ago.
A flutter clean and then flutter pub get seemed to do the trick for me. Might work for you too.

It worked before but after  week same problem occurs and now its not working for me
